# Determine if a path within an NSString is to a directory, or a file?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, file

I have an NSString containing a path, but it could be either a file, or a directory.

Is there an equivalent to the Python `os.path.isdir()` and `os.path.isfile()` methods in Cocoa?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

See the [NSFileManager Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilemanager/1410277-fileexistsatpath?language=objc)

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:pathname 
                                isDirectory:&directoryFlag];
```

For example:

```
NSString *file = @"/tmp/";
BOOL isDir = NO;
if([[NSFileManager defaultManager]
     fileExistsAtPath:file isDirectory:&isDir] && isDir){
    NSLog(@"Is directory");
}
```

Comment: The important thing here is that the BOOL you pass into the isDirectory: portion of the method is the real BOOL to see if the file is a folder! The BOOL that is returned from the fileExistsAtPath:isDirectory: is just confirming if a file is a the path.

Answer (score 2):

if the solution from htw doesn't work, try this:

```
NSString *file = @"/tmp/";
BOOL isDir
NSDirectoryEnumerator *dirEnum = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] enumeratorAtPath:file];
while ((file = [dirEnum nextObject])) {
   [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:file isDirectory:&isDir];
   if(isDir){
      NSLog(@"%@ is a directory", file);
   }
}
```

Comment: Your solution is actually same as how's but I'm afraid it contains a bug - the 'file' you get is a RELATIVE PATH (relative to the "/tmp") and not an absolute path, hence using 'fileExistsAtPath:isDirectory' on it - may fail. this method works on absolute paths.